# Laravel getting builder instead of relation

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to validate a model before saving it. Obviously if the model isn't valid, it shouldn't be saved to the database. When validation fails, it throws an exception and doesn't continue to save. This below works:

```
$question = new Question([...]);
$question->validate();
$question->save();
```

I have a problem with the `answers()` hasMany relationship. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23954060/977524) I should be able to call `add()` on the relation object:

```
$question = new Question([...]);
$question->answers()->add(new Answer([...]));
$question->validate();
$question->save();
```

The above fails:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::add()
```

I thought the answers() function would return a HasMany relationship object, but it looks like I'm getting a builder instead. Why?

Comment: If answers is a relationship, you'll want to call $question->answers  instead of $question->answers()  (don't invoke the function).  Make sure that you use the name of the function defining the relationship, and not the model name itself (it's ok if they're the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`answers()` does return a HasMany object. However, because there is no `add` method on a `HasMany` object, Laravel resorts to PHP's `__call` magic method.

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    $result = call_user_func_array([$this->query, $method], $parameters);

    if ($result === $this->query) {
        return $this;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The `__call` method gets the query instance and tries to call the `add` method on it. There is no `add` method on the query builder though, which is why you are getting that message.

Finally, the `add` method is part of Laravel's Eloquent Collection, not a part of HasMany. In order to get the Collection class, you need to drop the parenthesis (as shown in the answer provided in your link) and do this instead:

```
$question->answers->add(new Answer([...]));
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed the no-parentheses part.

Comment: Adding the answer to the collection will _not_ save it to the DB when the question is saved.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `add` method. Use the `save` method:

```
$question->answers()->save(new Answer([]));
```

Comment: I can't save the objects to the database before I perform validation, so I cannot sall save() on the collection.