# Set hasOne relation to new instance of child model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4.2, how can I set a hasOne relation on a model to an instance of a new model without touching the database?

I want to do the following, but Laravel is treating the instance as a property, not a child relation.

```
class ParentClass extends \Eloquent {
  public function child() {
    return $this-hasOne('ChildClass', 'child_id', 'parent_id');
  }
}

$parent = new ParentClass();
$parent->child = new ChildClass();
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used laravel but could you do `$parent = new ParentClass(); $parent->child()->create();`? Actually, I don't have an installation to test this on right now but `$parent->child() = new ChildClass();` may also work. You may jutst be missing the parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for response.


->create() wants to save to database.


->child() throws the error 'Can't use method return value in write context'.

Comment: Ok, how about this: `$child = new ChildClass(); $parent->child()->attach($child->id);`

Comment: ->attach is part of BelongsToMany and not hasOne so unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. After a little more reading, it seems what you're trying to do may not exactly be supported by eloquent. You may be able to get close enough though depending on what you're trying to do. First, if you look at the docs slightly below this anchor (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method), they describe the `associate` method which can be used to associate a child with a parent (though it sounds like you're trying to go the other way around).

Comment: If you look at the api (https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne.html) it doesn't seem there is a similar function to call on the parent to associate a child. You may be interested in this conversation though (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951222/eloquent-relations-attach-but-dont-save-to-has-many) where they seem to have found that this can be accomplished for `HasMany` relationships by just using `add`. I doubt `HasOne` is a collection as is the case for `HasMany` (I can't find proof in the docs/api) so it probably won't work, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: user2027202827, thanks for your responses and efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get through my problem, I have created a Trait class that I added to my models that allows me to set a relation.  Doing this does not automatically set my parent/child relation values so I have to be careful to do this manually before I save/push.

```
trait ModelSetRelationTrait
{
  public function setRelation($key, $model)
  {
    $this->relations[$key] = $model;
  }
}

class ParentClass extends \Eloquent {
  use ModelSetRelationTrait;
  public function child() {
    return $this-hasOne('ChildClass', 'child_id', 'parent_id');
  }
}
```