# Create models "on the fly" before its parent model is saved

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've been having this question for quite a long time. I guess it's more of a design problem. So I need to create a User with a mentor role that has many tutorships, but in the create user view I want to be able to add as many tutorships as I want. Once the tutorships are created, I want to be able to perform CRUD operations on them.

However, I want to be able to do this before actually saving its parent model (User) in the database. What is the common approach here? Am I supposed to create and then persist each Tutorship with an empty foreign key until I save the user? Or is it better if all the Tutorships are "floating around" until I save my user?

Comment: You can't pair things if there's nothing to pair them to. You will need to save them to the DB. You *may* be able to get away with putting something in a/the cache and then doing a batch update or something but that's rather poor from a systems/design standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I worked through this earlier.  I had created a trait I used on my models to allow setting relations and then I had to override the save and push on the model to work properly.

[Set hasOne relation to new instance of child model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416180/set-hasone-relation-to-new-instance-of-child-model)